# Android GCM error authentication sender account

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

It's been a while since I created a Android app with GCM integrated. Previously in the API console you would specify the server IP as a white list. However on my latest project this option is not there. Instead it asks for the SHA1 from the signing key which I have configured.

However when I try to send a notification to a registered device ID I get

"There was an error authenticating the sender account"

I am using the correct API key so I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 1):

**Previously in the API console you would specify the server IP as a white list. However on my latest project this option is not there**

This section is found when you generate a SERVER API key in your GDC.

**"There was an error authenticating the sender account"**

Found this on [GCM Authentication](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http) guide. Make sure these are implemented.

> A message request is made of 2 parts:  HTTP header and HTTP body.
>
> The HTTP header must contain the following headers:
>
> Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY Content-Type: application/json for
>   JSON; application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 for plain text.
>   If Content-Type is omitted, the format is assumed to be plain text.

For example:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

**Additional Note:**

[Authentication Error 401](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) - The sender account used to send a message couldn't be authenticated.

> Possible causes are:
>
> -Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax in HTTP request.
>
> -Invalid project number sent as key.
>
> -Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
>
> -Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs. Check that the token you're sending inside the Authentication
>   header is the correct API key associated with your project. See
>   [Checking the validity of an API
>   Key](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#checkAPIkey)
>   for details.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Messaging defaults to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) now. Use the Server Key provided in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com).

Before that, you may also need to Import your Google Cloud Project into Firebase if you have one.

[Import instructions](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/google-android#migrate_your_console_project) (only follow the "Migrate your console project" section)